# FOR loop every file in folder and perform COMP + MOVE in BAT file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, compare

I have 2 folders (dir A and dir B) that contain the same financial reports in the form of `.csv` files, but with **possibly** different values.

I am trying to reconcile these reports by doing away with the ones that are the same but I am also trying to write a `.bat` file that performs the comparison and in addition, shifts the respective files to other folders conditional on if differences are found or not for that **particular** file.

I want the `.bat` file to:

1. Loop through every file in dir A
2. For every file, compare (COMP) it to its equivalent in dir B (file names will be the same)
3. If there are no differences - move (MOVE) the files from dir A and dir B to dir C and dir D, respectively.
4. If there are differences - do nothing; leave the files in dir A and B, and continue the loop

My program looked a little something like this (obviously incomplete):

```
@echo off
:Main
FOR /D %%X ("C:\youl\dirA") DO COMP %%X C:\youl\dirB
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO Next1

:Next1
Copy C:\youl\dirA C:\youl\dirB
```

Obviously this is a pretty horrendous and inoperable piece of code for my purposes.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Updated from npocmaka's code:

```
@echo off

Setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
set "dirA=c:\users\youl\automation\binarycheck\A\*.csv"
set "dirB=c:\users\youl\automation\binarycheck\B\*.csv"
set "dirC=c:\users\youl\automation\binarycheck\C\"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" &&a in ("%dirA&") do (
        fc /b "%%a" "%dirB%" >nul 2>&1 && (
            move "%%a" "%dirC%"
        )
)

endlocal
```

Comment: do you want recursive traverse or flat?

Comment: Start with `for %%g in ("C:\youl\dirA\*.csv") do @echo %%g`, see result and then [learn](http://ss64.com/nt/) on `FOR` (running multiple commands in a `FOR` loop), [learn](http://ss64.com/nt/) on `IF condition (commands) ELSE (commands)`, [learn](http://ss64.com/nt/) on `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`, [learn](http://ss64.com/nt/) ...

Comment: I am trying to figure this out myself as well but I don't have complete privilege in terms of time as I need find a solution fairly quickly. I can get the FOR loop working, it's my conditional "MOVE" that is broken as it's treating the entire program as one (i.e. set of files) as opposed to looking at the ERRORLEVEL at each file level. So either all my files get moved or none, which is not what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not sure npocmaka - indeed it is all on the same drive. Apologies, I should been clearer that I am talking about simple Windows folders when refering dir A and dir B

Comment: Your `errorlevel` problem is simple. `if errorlevel n` means *if errorlevel is n* **or is greater than n**. Hence `if errorlevel 0` is, except in exceptional circumstances, always true. To test for 0, use `if not errorlevel 1`.

Comment: Hi Magooo

Actually what you wrote here helped a lot. I almost have it working to the level I want - just needs a tiny bit more tweaking. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

**NOT TESTED!**

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "dirA=c:\dir1"
set "dirB=c:\dir2"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "%dirA%"') do (
        set "path1=%%~pa"
        set "path2=!path1:%dirA%=%dirB%!"
        fc /b "%%~fa" "%%~da!path2!%%~nxa" >nul 2>&1 && (
            move "%%~fa" "%%~da!path2!%%~nxa"
        )
)

endlocal
```

Assumed that you need recursive check and `dirA` and `dirB` are on the same drive...

Comment: Many thanks for this - but it seems that you have included FC when really I am probably looking for COMP. Also it's not entirely clear to me where the files are being moved as part of the "MOVE" function.

Comment: @Youl - why you need explicitly `COMP` command ? `COMP` will need piped `echo n` to stop prompting for another comparision...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't FC just check the size of the files? I want to avoid a situation where I have two files that have the same size, but different values in the data - if that makes sense. However, even with FC, I'm not clear on what is happening when this program is executed with respect to the MOVE.

I believe it's going through each file in Folder A and comparing it to its counterpart in Folder B. But not sure what the logic is saying with respect to what happens if files match or not.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html  - size is just the first thing checked by FC. It's far more advanced command than COMP

Comment: I see what you mean npocmaka, in that case FC will be fine.

I have taken your code and changed it around a bit to see if I could make it work because it wasn't exactly working for me. It's almost at a stage that is fine except that it is applying the MOVE logic across the entire folder as opposed as taking it file by file. If all files have no difference, then they are moved to new folder. However, if only 1 file has difference, ALL files stay when actually I would want that 1 file with differences to be moved. I'll update the main post

Comment: I believe if we are just going to treat the files as a "set" then we wouldn't need the FOR loop in the first place, as far I can tell. Any ideas?